# How to check whether a browser is installed in the machine using Java?

Tags: java

I want to check whether a browser is installed on my machine using Java. That is I want to check whether Firefox,chrome etc is installed through my java code.

Comment: If it is UI application, ask to user to specify path of browser exactly.Otherwise you can scan hard-drive, (browser usual places) to find their.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Also where is this Java code running?

Comment: I wanted to create an application for testers. The applications asks the tester to input the browser in which they want to do the testing. Before directly trying to load the browser, I wanted to do a check whether the entered browser is installed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible unless you have to scan through the OS directories e.g. in program files and check for browser excutable files. You might also as well run into permission problems.

Comment: I think I got the answer, which is actually a work around. That is check for the browser version. Any other work around?

Comment: If your OS is Windows another way is to search in the Windows registry using some registry search Java API but then you have to search for one online.